# how can i convert ExecuteNonQuery result in templet inside(T) using C#

Tags: c#

how can i convert ExecuteNonQuery result in templet inside(T) using C#.

i am develop new generic method is sqlCommand result is convert any data type inside.

```
example

Result<T>.Data =cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
value is not store data inside.
```

Result class

public static class Result
    {

```
    public static bool Sucess { get; set; }
    public static T Data { get; set; }
    public static bool ReturnValue { get; set; }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might benefit from going through a basic tutorial on data access.

`ExecuteNonQuery()` **does not return an Sql result set**. It only returns the number of rows affected by the query. You probably want `ExecuteScalar()` or `ExecuteDataReader()`.

Instead of `Result<T>`, you need a `Result<int>` or `Result<string>` or `Result<DateTime>`, etc. You use `T` when *declaring* a generic class or method, but you want actual types when *using* a generic type or method you've previously declared.

Assuming you use `ExecuteSclar()`, you must cast the result to your desired `T` type.

You need an *instance* of the class. Instead of just `Result<int>.Data =` you must do something more like this:

```
var result = new Result<int>();
result.Data = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

And that's basic enough a data access tutorial may not be enough, and you might first consider looking at some basic C# training.